# Proof of Kelvin-Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

The Kelvin-Stokes' Theorem states that for a $C^1$ vector field on a smooth surface $S$,
$$\oint_{\partial S}\mathbf{F}\cdot ds=\iint_S\nabla\times\mathbf{F}\cdot d\sigma.$$
All proofs I can find ([including this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem#Elementary_proof)) uses the mixed derivative theorem on the parametrization of the surface, which is not assumed in the statement of the theorem. Is there any way to prove the theorem without invoking the mixed derivative theorem?

Comment: What's your reason for not wanting to invoke the mixed derivative theorem? I didn't understand that.

Comment: @LittleO: Is there a guarantee that there is always a parametrization of the surface $\varphi(u,v)$ such that $\varphi_{uv}=\varphi_{vu}$ ?

Comment: @ashpool A smooth surface is usually defined by means of a smooth parametrization

Comment: @Caffeine: In most calculus books, a "smooth parametrization" $\varphi(u,v)$ of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is usually defined by requiring that $\varphi_u$ and $\varphi_v$ are continuous, and $\varphi_u\times\varphi_v\neq\mathbf{0}$. This essentially means a continuous parametrization of tangent spaces. I now realized that (I think this is what you are getting at), "smooth manifold" refers to quite another thing ($C^{\infty}$ atlas)...